# Is there a way to disable auto-save in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: autosave, disable

I've searched this online, but all the answers seem to be for outdated versions of VS and didn't work for me.  I would like to disable Visual Studio 2017's auto-save function, as I'm making a lot of mistakes lately and need to be able to revert to my original save instead of closing the project and saving the mistakes unintentionally.  Does anyone know of a way to turn off this feature?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but a possible solution for you is to use a source control system like git, SVN, mercurial, perforce.  That way you can save a known-good revision of your entire project and revert back to that at any time.

Comment: thanks man, I'll give that a shot